# Can one do pull-ups right after a meal?

Tags: muscle, food, pull-ups

I am generally healthy. Just wondering if it is safe to do pull-ups within 10-15 min of having lunch. I am trying to avoid any exercises that might affect digestion. Are pull-ups "safe"?

Moreover, I am not trying to a lot of reps right after meals. My intention is to keep myself awake/alert. Going for a walk is not an option (small office, little space outside)

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_%28exercise%29#Safety) wikipedia article, which does not say anything on my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After meal assuming you did not drink much water after finishing meal.  You should take 20mins rest. 
Since our digestion process starts and and doing max 10 (no reps) pull ups / chin ups after rest would be fine, since you said you don't want to go for walk.

Comment: Can you provide any sources for your claims? Sounds like guesswork and anecdotal evidence from personal experience.

Answer (score 4):

Exercising after eating is safe. The other answers here are based on personal opinions.

When you eat, the process of digestion is aided by the parasympathetic nervous system (rest and digest). When you exercise your sympathetic nervous system releases adrenaline, which inhibits the peristaltis in your gut. This in terms makes the food move more slowly through your intestines and causes indigestion. Some of the effects of this are heartburn, bloating and diarrhea. However, this is very individual, as it depends on the ratio of activation of your sympathetic versus your parasympathetic nervous system when exercising. Some people can eat right before and not feel anything, while others need at least 2h before practice. Just doing pull ups will not get your adrenaline pumping as much as doing whole body training such as sprinting or doing contact sports.

Try doing pull ups after your meal and see how you feel. Purely medically there are no dangers of doing pull ups after eating.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule I try to wait 30 mins after a meal before doing any type of lifting (45-60mins before I attempt cardio)

If I workout any time less than this I can feel quite sickly.

Also depends what you have ate, a light sandwich is no problem, give it 15-20 mins, if your having a hefty meal you probably want close to an hour.